# How many ways are there to divide $100$ different balls into $5$ different boxes so the last $2$ boxes contains even number of balls?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to divide $100$ different balls into $5$ different boxes so the last $2$ boxes contains even number of balls?

I tried to think about tylor function but got stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g_{e}(x)=\displaystyle\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)^3\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)^2=(e^x)^3\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=\displaystyle e^{3x}\left(\frac{e^{2x}+2+e^{-2x}}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{4}(e^{5x}+2e^{3x}+e^x)$.

The coefficient of $x^{100}$ is given by $\displaystyle\frac{a_{100}}{100!}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{5^{100}}{100!}+2\cdot\frac{3^{100}}{100!}+\frac{1}{100!}\right)$,  so

$\hspace{1.5 in}$ $\displaystyle a_{100}=\frac{1}{4}(5^{100}+2\cdot3^{100}+1)$.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: I am using exponential generating functions, so each factor corresponds to the balls chosen for a given box.  The first three boxes have no restrictions, so there are all powers of x in the first 3 factors; but the last two boxes have an even number of balls, so the last two factors only have even powers of x.  (Notice that the hyperbolic cosine appears because of this.)