# Combinatorics problem using generating functions 1

Tags: combinatorics, exponential-function, generating-functions

In how many ways can you divide $n$ different balls into $5$ different boxes so that the two last boxes has an even number of balls.

I've been given a clue to show that: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^{2n} \over (2n)!} = {e^x + e^{-x} \over 2}$

My thought was using the $e^x$ Taylor's series, but i don't really getting anything.

I'll be happy to get partial solution , or any explaination on how should I approach this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this one out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905229/how-many-ways-are-there-to-divide-100-different-balls-into-5-different-boxes

Comment: I think you were on the right track by subbing in the taylor series for $e^x$. The two series for $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ will cancel out odd terms (since these terms are opposite signs) and leave you only the even terms.

Comment: Do you know $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}+e^{x}}{2}=\cosh(x)$ and $\cosh'(x)=\sinh(x),\ \sinh'(x)=\cosh(x)$?. Then use Taylor series.

Comment: @Albert How does cosine hyperbolic function gonna help me decide how many options to divide n balls into 5 different boxes? and  what about the last two boxes? I'll be happy for some light shed over the connections and the rationalization of these problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combinatorial species here is

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=3}(\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{Z}))
\mathfrak{S}_{=2}(\mathfrak{P}_{\mathrm{even}}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This immediately produces the generating function

$$G(z) = \exp(z)^3 \frac{(\exp(z)+\exp(-z))^2}{4}.$$

which is

$$G(z) = \frac{1}{4}(\exp(5z)+2\exp(3z)+\exp(z)).$$

Coefficient extraction produces the formula
$$n! [z^n] G(z)
= \frac{1}{4} 5^n + \frac{1}{2} 3^n + \frac{1}{4}.$$

This yields the sequence
$$3, 11, 45, 197, 903, 4271, 20625, 100937, 498123, 
2470931, 12295605,\ldots$$

which is [OEIS A146086](https://oeis.org/A146086).

The OEIS confirms the above derivation because it says we are counting
numbers consisting  of $n$  odd digits where  the one and  three digit
occur an even  number of times.  This is the  same as partitioning the
$n$ positions into three sets for  the five digit, the seven digit and
the nine  digit and two  sets for the  one digit and the  three digit,
where the latter two must contain  an even number of elements. This is
precisely the problem definition.

**Addendum.** Consulting the linked to answer from the comments which I hadn't seen it appears to be correct and complete and hence renders this question a duplicate.

Comment: Are the balls distinguishable or indistinguishable? Does each of the last two boxes have an even number of balls, or is it just the total number of balls in the last two boxes that has to be even?

Comment: The problem statement says distinguishable balls, which is what I worked with. Given the hint I assumed the parity constraint applies to the individual last two boxes.

Comment: Your final answer is what I eventually got, but how you did it, I got absolutely no clue. Those symbols?? Immediately produce this function? If you got the time I would be thankful for a further explanation on how you see it so immediately.

Comment: This [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics) has the notation and additional material including links.